# Is there a way to grant access to a Private MSMQ Queue with a username and password

Tags: security, msmq

I am trying to allow someone from outside of our AD to access a private message queue for reading and another one for sending. I don't want to add them to our AD. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add them to the local user store, on the Windows hosting MSMQ?
MSMQ can authenticate users either via AD, or against Windows own local users (SAM). Note however that if your servers are clustered, this can be more complicated.